# Change the sample by using goroutine?

Tags: go, web-crawler, goroutine

I found a good web invalid links checker. But how to change it for a complete sample by using goroutine? The web page is: [How To Crawl A Website In Golang](http://leantricks.com/code/how-to-crawl-a-website-in-golang/). The codes dynamically add the url that will be searched to the `pending` slice. but I have some difficulties to use goroutine to do it.

```
package main
import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/html"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
    "time"
)
var alreadyCrawledList []string
var pending []string
var brokenLinks []string
const localHostWithPort = "localhost:8080"
func IsLinkInPendingQueue(link string) bool {
    for _, x := range pending {
        if x == link {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
func IsLinkAlreadyCrawled(link string) bool {
    for _, x := range alreadyCrawledList {
        if x == link {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
func AddLinkInAlreadyCrawledList(link string) {
    alreadyCrawledList = append(alreadyCrawledList, link)
}
func AddLinkInPendingQueue(link string) {
    pending = append(pending, link)
}
func AddLinkInBrokenLinksQueue(link string) {
    brokenLinks = append(brokenLinks, link)
}
func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    AddLinkInPendingQueue("http://" + localHostWithPort)
    for count := 0; len(pending) > 0; count++ {
        x := pending[0]
        pending = pending[1:]  //it dynamicly change the search url
        if err := crawlPage(x); err != nil {  //how to use it by using goroutine?
            t.Errorf(err.Error())
        }
    }
    duration := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println("________________")
    count = 0
    for _, l := range brokenLinks {
        count++
        fmt.Println(count, "Broken. | ", l)
    }
    fmt.Println("Time taken:", duration)
}
func crawlPage(uri string) error {
    if IsLinkAlreadyCrawled(uri) {
        fmt.Println("Already visited: Ignoring uri | ", uri)
        return nil
    }
    transport := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        },
    }
    client := http.Client{Transport: transport}
    resp, err := client.Get(uri)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Got error: ", err.Error())
        return err
    }
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        AddLinkInBrokenLinksQueue(uri)
        return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Got %v instead of 200", resp.StatusCode))
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    links := ParseLinks(resp.Body)
    links = ConvertLinksToLocalHost(links)
    for _, link := range links {
        if !InOurDomain(link) {
            continue
        }
        absolute := FixURL(link, uri)
        if !IsLinkAlreadyCrawled(absolute) && !IsLinkInPendingQueue(absolute) && absolute != uri { // Don't enqueue a page twice!
            AddLinkInPendingQueue(absolute)
        }
    }
    AddLinkInAlreadyCrawledList(uri)
    return nil
}
func InOurDomain(link string) bool {
    uri, err := url.Parse(link)
    if err != nil {
        return false
    }
    if uri.Scheme == "http" || uri.Scheme == "https" {
        if uri.Host == localHostWithPort {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    return true
}
func ConvertLinksToLocalHost(links []string) []string {
    var convertedLinks []string
    for _, link := range links {
        convertedLinks = append(convertedLinks, strings.Replace(link, "leantricks.com", localHostWithPort, 1))
    }
    return convertedLinks
}
func FixURL(href, base string) string {
    uri, err := url.Parse(href)
    if err != nil {
        return ""
    }
    baseURL, err := url.Parse(base)
    if err != nil {
        return ""
    }
    uri = baseURL.ResolveReference(uri)
    return uri.String()
}
func ParseLinks(httpBody io.Reader) []string {
    var links []string
    page := html.NewTokenizer(httpBody)
    for {
        tokenType := page.Next()
        if tokenType == html.ErrorToken {
            return links
        }

        token := page.Token()
        switch tokenType {
        case html.StartTagToken:
            fallthrough
        case html.SelfClosingTagToken:
            switch token.DataAtom.String() {
            case "a":
                fallthrough
            case "link":
                fallthrough
            case "script":
                for _, attr := range token.Attr {
                    if attr.Key == "href" {
                        links = append(links, attr.Val)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you taking a look at an [example](https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/blob/master/ch8/crawl3/findlinks.go) of a concurrent web crawler from the famous book.

Answer (score 1):

You could invoke the crawlPage() concurrently and handle `alreadyCrawledList`, `pending` and `brokenLinks` variables with mutexes (not so performant though). On the other hand, the code needs to be modified a lot to get it more performant.

I did a quick check with 4 links and seems to half the duration. I did a sample code with a simple http server and its [here](https://github.com/maniankara/stackoverflow/tree/master/golang-web-crawler-with-goroutines)

Thanks,
 - Anoop

Comment: It is not what i want. because the ```BrokenLinks``` need to be searched, but not  the known result. @Maniankara

Comment: @user3373877, can you explain a bit more? From the above link, you can see that I have tested also broken link: https://github.com/maniankara/stackoverflow/blob/master/golang-web-crawler-with-goroutines/crawl.go#L210. Also, I havent modified the functionality from here: http://leantricks.com/code/how-to-crawl-a-website-in-golang/

Comment: https://github.com/megaserg/validation-crawler/blob/master/crawler.go is what i want.   the goroutine and the channel is used by it.